# Getting an On-Behalf-Of access token with a token obtained using the implicit flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

TL;DR: I want to use implicit flow to get an access token and have the user consent my app to grab the profile from Microsoft Graph. When getting the on-behalf-of token on the server side, it complains that no consent is given.

I have a client application getting an access token from Azure Active Directory using the implicit flow.  I'm using MSAL, and it is retrieving the scopes `openid`, `profile` and `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`.

`var app = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(clientId, authority, () => onTokenReceived(...), {
      postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/logout',
      redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/login-redirect'
});
app.loginRedirect('https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read');`

I grab the access token for the scope `<clientid>` from this and use it as a bearer token to authenticate my against my API.

`var tokenPromise = app.acquireTokenSilent(['<clientid>'])`

On the server side I'm wanting to read the user profile from Graph, so I'm requesting one the provided access token using MSAL and the On-behalf-of flow.

Instead of working, an error: `AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID '<clientid>' named '<name>'. Send an interactive authorization request for this user and resource.`

I expected that requesting the `User.Read` scope of Graph would give the consent required.  When I check http://myapps.microsoft.com for this user, I have a bunch of permissions (I went crazy adding a bunch that I likely don't need):

`Sign you in and read your profile
Sign in as you
Access your data anytime
View your basic profile
Access the directory as you
Sign you in and read your profile`

Note that this works if I give admin consent - it's only when the user has to give consent that it falls over.  None of the permissions above require admin consent, according to the permissions area of the app registration.

What am I missing?

Comment: Your applicaiton needs admin consent to achieve this on-behalf-of flow indeed. You can also add the `User.Read.All` scope for your application.

Comment: Thanks @WayneYang-MSFT, is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly.  If you just use implicit flow, the scope should just contains which you need and the applicaiton just needs user to give consent for them. But if you want application to instead of on behalf of a user, you need admin consent indeed. Here is a sample:https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-daemon-v2   Please feel free to let me know if it helps

Comment: That's not quite the same thing - I'm trying to use `application.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOfAsync(...)`.  When I say "on behalf of user" I don't mean instead of, I mean the specific flow that's described here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-on-behalf-of which has the note "In this scenario, the middle-tier service has no user interaction to obtain the user's consent to access the downstream API. Therefore, the option to grant access to the downstream API is presented upfront as a part of the consent step during authentication."

Comment: Right, since On-Behalf-Of returns a refresh token, you need the offline_access scope. The not so awesome thing about v2 is that consent appears still not done for some seconds. Cache invalidation problems can occur which did not happen in v1 (usually).

Comment: Oh right...I added that scope to the app required permissions but not in my requested scopes for the implicit flow.  I wonder if I can, implicit flow isn't exactly famous for supporting refresh tokens.  I'll give it a whirl and come back here. Thanks

Comment: So I gave this a whirl, set my scopes to `'offline_access', 'openid', 'profile', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read'` and I got an access token - but it doesn't give me access to query my group membership `Code: Authorization_RequestDenied. Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`  A quick looksy around states I need the `Directory.AccessAsUser.All` scope to do this, which does indeed need Admin consent.

Comment: Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-permission-scopes - "Note: A native client app can have the user consent to this permission however, a web app requires administrator consent."